# PhpStorm HTTP requests return 404 unless they are of type GET or POST

Tags: php, curl, phpstorm

[image: OPTIONS request through PHP Storms built in rest client]
returns:

```
<!doctype html><title>404 Not Found</title><h1 style="text-align: center">404 Not Found</h1><hr/><p style="text-align: center">PhpStorm 2017.2.4</p>
```

[image: GET request through PHP Storms built in rest client]

returns:

```
Reached File
200
```

The PHP file is simply

```
<?php
echo "Reached File\n";
echo http_response_code(200);
```

This same behavior is exhibited using curl (or any other method of sending an HTTP request)

GET:

```
curl http://localhost:63342/CSCD-378%20-%20Web%20Development/CSCD-378/5-REST/api/v1/vin/index.php
```

POST:

```
curl -X OPTIONS http://localhost:63342/CSCD-378%20-%20Web%20Development/CSCD-378/5-REST/api/v1/vin/index.php
```

PhpStorm is configured to use /usr/bin/php as the interpreter

PhpStorm version 2016.2.4
OS = Linux Mint 18.2

Comment: This isn't the first time I've seen issues with PHPStorm's built-in HTTP server. I suggest you use PHP's built-in server instead

Comment: yup, looks like built-in server doesn't allow this method. Please try that on a fully operational web server (apache).